Nuxt composable loosing it's context
i implemented composable that takes an argument, which can be a render function
import { VMessage } from '../components/Message';

export function useMessage (props: IVMessageProps) {
    const { body } = document;
    const VMessageNode = createVNode(VMessage, props);

    VMessageNode.props!.onClose = () => {
        render(null, body);
    };

    render(VMessageNode, body);
}

So i use it like that
useMessage({
title: 'hello world',
theme: 'primary',
message: h(RouterLink, {to: '/cart'}, 'to cart')
})

But the problem that it doesnt render it as 'a' tag, instead it render it like 'router-link' component, what am i doing wrong?
Plus the problem that i can't use any composables (useRoute, useRouter etc) in components rendered via 'h' function
the error is "cannot read properties of undefined reading $nuxt"
I think it's because my component looses context, what can i do here?


export function useMessage (props: IVMessageProps) {
const { body } = document;
const { vueApp }  = useNuxtApp();
const VMessageNode = createVNode(VMessage, props);

if (vueApp._context) {
    VMessageNode.appContext = vueApp._context;
}
VMessageNode.props!.onClose = () => {
    render(null, body);
};

render(VMessageNode, body);

}
I have added  nuxt context to my component and it works, anyway i don't understand if it's a good approach, if u know a better way comment here pls

Please create a minimal reproducible example

You create a new vue app where RouterLink isn't registered. What you listed in the comment is a known hack that relies on framework internals. A safer solution is to not use render() but use public vue apis. In this case this would be a teleport in App or other top-level component. A composable can interact with it in some way, e.g. through global store
